# Query classnames of checked items as array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have many checkboxes on a page, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="cb_31" class="observedType1">
<input type="checkbox"  id="cb_32" class="observedType1" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox"  id="cb_33" class="observedType1">
<input type="checkbox"  id="cb_40" class="observedType2" checked="checked">
```

I then wanted to retrieve the classes of all checked boxes in an array (ideally as a list of unique items), so I'm looking to for `['observedType1'l'observedType2'].`
My best idea was: 
`var clss=$("[class*='observedType']:checked").attr("class");` 
but that only gives me a string "`observedType1`".

How can I get the array I am looking for? (or a "list" to walk through in a loop)...

There's also a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mbaas/27dc8kga/1/)

Comment: you almost got it you just need to iterate on all the checked checkbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate all the `:checked` checkboxes, here you can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var clss=$("[class*='observedType']:checked").map(function(){
   return $(this).attr('class')
}).get();
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/27dc8kga/2/)

---

I would recommend you to use custom `data-*` prefix custom attribute to store the arbitrary data.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb_31" class="observedType" data-type="observedType1">
```

Which can be retrieved using `.data()` method

```
var clss = $(".observedType:checked").map(function() {
  return $(this).data('type')
}).get();
```

[With Custom attribute Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/27dc8kga/5/)

Comment: Cool stuff - thanks! Especially for `data-* `!

Comment: Updated your fiddle so that actually works with the custom-attribute AND added unique...

Answer (score 1):

you can  do the following in javascript :

```
var myInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var myCheckedInputs = Array.from(myInputs).filter(function(input) {
  return input.checked;
});
```